# Systemd - A Stop Job Is Running

Tags: systemd

I am on Arch Linux Raspberry Pi. I have a Ruby script that blinks LED light connected to GPIO pin 7 (https://github.com/Souravgoswami/others/blob/master/ActivityBlink/activity_blink.rb). There's no problem with that.

But to start that script as root at boot, I have created a systemd service without much understanding:

```
[Unit]
Description=A simple script to send GPIO output based on storage device activity.

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=!!/usr/bin/activity_blink
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3
User=root
Group=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now I enabled the service:
`sudo systemctl enable activity_blink`

After that, on boot, it works fine, but at the time of shutting down the system, it keeps saying:

```
[*** ] A stop job is running for A simple script to send GPIO output based on storage device activity. (15s / 5min 30s).
```

What's wrong with the service script?
How can I change the behaviour without changing anything from system.conf?

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong?

Comment: It always says a stop job is running ... And it takes more than 5 minutes to shutdown the system. That's a huge problem for me!

Comment: Try to define `ExecStop=...` and stop yourelf `activity_blink`.